# My later function shows execution time error when I try to send a mail

Tags: laravel, eloquent

First I save the file in my public folder, then I want to send an email to the admin with that file attached.

```
public function upload(Request $request){   

    if($file = $request->file('pre_qualification')){
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('submissions', $name);

        $form = Form::create([
            'pre_qualification'=> $name,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ]);

        $today=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." +2 minutes"));

        Mail::later($today,new PreQualificationNotification($form));

        return redirect()->route('buyer.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Then this is in my Mailable class:

```
public function __construct($form)
{
    $this->form = $form;
    $this->to('esp.sousa@gmail.com', $this->form->user->name);
    $this->subject('See attached new pre-qualification form submitted');
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.PreQualification')
    ->attach(public_path('/submissions/pre-qualification.pdf'));
}
```

After I submit, the file goes to the public folder, but when I view the page I see an execution time error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

The idea of using the later function was exactly to avoid that. So, how can I send the email to the admin, attaching the uploaded file?

Comment: How big is your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change max_execution_time=30 in php.ini to some bigger amount.
Or better to use max_execution_time ( int $seconds ) in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
set_time_limit( int $seconds );
```